# Getting an error as "Using pre-existing current store at URL" while use module in Titanium app

Tags: ios, xcode, module, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm trying to develop iOS module with Appcelerator Studio, And i have done that perfectly, Also built the module using ./build.py

But facing an issue while require that module in Titanium classic app, I just tried to run the app in iOS simulator with classicTestApp project And getting the below error,

```
[INFO] :   Invoking xcodebuild
[ERROR] :  2016-03-25 12:58:40.851 xcodebuild[24711:5b03]  DeveloperPortal: Using pre-existing current store at URL (file:///Users /silambu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeveloperPortal%206.0.1.db).
[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   Ld build/Intermediates/classicTestApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/classicTestApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/classicTestApp normal x86_64
[ERROR] :   Ld build/Intermediates/classicTestApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/classicTestApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/classicTestApp normal i386
[ERROR] :  (2 failures)
```

Can you suggest me the solution?

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project via Studio or `[appc] ti clean` first?